# Running a web crawler for selected sites on google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, web-crawler, nutch

I need to write a crawler to extract some info from few pre-slected websites only.

I know this is a straightway job but am thinking of using google app engine to get this done.

May be I can try Nutch to do this for me.

How feasible is this way of getting it done?

1) hosting a crawler on google infrastructure
2) Nutch + app engine- will it be possible?

Answer (score 4):

Just glancing over the [nutch docs](http://nutch.apache.org/), I see comments like "[t]his is the second release of Nutch based entirely on the underlying Hadoop platform" 
which make me suspect this will not run on [App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/).  App Engine apps run in a [Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#The_Sandbox) or [Java](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#The_Sandbox) sandbox.

That said, you should be able to put a basic crawler together on App Egnine.  I basic implementation would probably involve launching [tasks](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/) that use [urlfetch](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/) to grab pages, and then, optionally, insert additional tasks to process links the document links to.  You can kick the crawl off using [scheduled tasks](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron.html).

Comment: he would essentially write a crawler from scratch, isn't it?

Comment: @simpatico yeah, more or less.